Flutter stream_transform droppable function not defined
I'm following a tutorial on Flutter Bloc and I'm having an issue with the stream_transform library.
I copied the exact code from the tutorial but I'm still getting an error:
EventTransformer<E> throttleDroppable<E>(Duration duration) {
  return (events, mapper) {
    return droppable<E>().call(events.throttle(duration), mapper);
  };
}

the function 'droppable' isn't defined.
Does this have something to do with the library?
Imports don't seem to be the issue...

You should import bloc_concurrency : import 'package:bloc_concurrency/bloc_concurrency.dart';
so in a basic bloc with with stream transform, you have this structure:
import 'package:bloc_concurrency/bloc_concurrency.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:stream_transform/stream_transform.dart';
part 'some_event.dart';
part 'some_state.dart';

const throttleDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 100);

EventTransformer<E> throttleDroppable<E>(Duration duration) {
  return (events, mapper) {
    return droppable<E>().call(events.throttle(duration), mapper);
  };
}
class SomeBloc extends Bloc<SomeEvent, SomeState> {
  SomeBloc() : super(SomeInitialState()) {
    on<SomeEvent>((event, emit) {
      // TODO: implement event handler
    });
  }
}


@lan you should accept the answer if it worked.
